# GlazedList - Filter table based on 1 column only

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter, glazedlists

I'm using GlazedList for handling JTables in my Swing project implemented using MVC pattern. I have the following code in my controller for incorporating filtering functionality in the table.

```
    final JTextField txtFilter = view.getTxtSearch();
    FilterList<E> textFilteredSource = new FilterList<E>(model.getDataTableSource(), new TextComponentMatcherEditor<E>(txtFilter, new TextFilterator<E>() {
        public void getFilterStrings(List baseList, E element) {
           Person p = (Person) element;
           baseList.add(p.getFirstName());
           baseList.add(p.getLastName());
           baseList.add(p.getBirthDay());
           baseList.add(p.getAge());
           baseList.add(p.getOccupation());
        }
    }));

model.setDataTableSource(textFilteredSource);
```

The above code allows my table to filter based on all the data present in the whole table. What I want is a functionality that only filters the table based on one column only. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for those who'll encounter the same problem, I solved it myself through experimenting, and I found out that the `baseList` is actually a list of String where the `FilterList` will do its filtering job. To do my requirement, I just added the column value that I need to be filtered to the `baseList` parameter.

The following code will filter the table based on the combobox selected index coming from the view.

```
    public void getFilterStrings(List baseList, E element) {
       JComboBox cbo = view.getCboSearch();
       int selIndex = cbo.getSelectedIndex();
       Person p = (Person) element;

       if(selIndex == 0)
          baseList.add(p.getFirstName());
       else if(selIndex == 1)
          baseList.add(p.getLastName());
       else if(selIndex == 2)
          baseList.add(p.getBirthDay());
       else if(selIndex == 3)
          baseList.add(p.getAge());
       else if(selIndex == 4)
          baseList.add(p.getOccupation());
    }
```